# PHP: Increment the variable each time you run the function

Tags: php, laravel, class

I have a function in my Helper Class that should increment the variable each time the function is called.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

class Helper 
{

  public static $count;

  public static function voiceHelper($questionArray)
  {
    $count = self::$count;
    // $count = 0;
    if(count($questionArray) >= $count)
    {
        $count++;
        return $count;

    } else if($count > count($questionArray))
    {
        $count == 0;
        return $count;
    }
   }

}
```

I expect that the count variable will increment each time the function is called but it still remains 1.

Comment: @Joseph_J Yes. For example the variable questionArray length is 3 and still it doesn't increment even though it passes the condition.

Comment: fix " $count == 0;" to " $count = 0;"

Comment: Really not sure about this design, it looks as though it's iterating through a list of questions.  If it is, then create an object with a list of questions and then have a `next()` method.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
class Helper 
{

  public static $count;

  public static function voiceHelper($questionArray)
  {

    // $count = 0;
    if(count($questionArray) >= $count)
    {
        self::$count++;
        return self::$count;

    } else if($count > count($questionArray))
    {
        self::$count = 0;
        return self::$count;
    }
   }

}
```

Looks like you are just incrementing the `$count` without adding it to the static count property.  Therefore you will always get 1.  Instead actually increment the static count property.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `self::$count` everywhere:

```
<?php

    class Helper 
    {

        public static $count;

        public static function voiceHelper($questionArray)
        {

            if(count($questionArray) >= self::$count)
            {
                self::$count++;
                return self::$count;

            }

            if(self::$count > count($questionArray))
            {
                self::$count = 0; // change == to = as it's assignment
                return self::$count;
            }
        }

    }
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/EaEqA  And https://3v4l.org/pto7m

Note:- You did increment in the `$count` without adding it to the static count property. That's why you always got 1.